# Showing form within another one

Tags: python, django

I want to show a form within another form.

For example I have these models:

```
class Measure(models.Model):

    length = models.ForeignKey(Statistics, related_name='Length', null=True, blank=True)
    surface_area = models.ForeignKey(Statistics, related_name='Surface area+', null=True, blank=True)
    section_area = models.ForeignKey(Statistics, related_name='Section area+', null=True, blank=True)
    volume = models.ForeignKey(Statistics, related_name='Volume', null=True, blank=True)
    diameter = models.ForeignKey(Statistics, related_name='Diameter', null=True, blank=True)


class Statistics(models.Model):
    total = models.FloatField('Total', null=True, blank=True)
    avg = models.FloatField('Average', null=True, blank=True)
    min = models.FloatField('Minimum', null=True, blank=True)
    max = models.FloatField('Maximum', null=True, blank=True)
    standard_deviation = models.FloatField('Standard deviation', null=True, blank=True)
```

and then I have these forms corresponding to the previous models:

```
class StatisticsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistics
        fields = '__all__'

class MeasureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Measure
        fields = '__all__'

        # Here I have to say that the right form for each field is the StatisticForm
```

The ForeignKey in the forms is rendered as a combo box includes all the objects in the other table (in my case the Statistics table), I want to replace the combo box with an object of StatisticsForm so I can control the way I render the Statistics objects

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, but it sounds like you are looking for [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: The ForeignKey in the forms is rendered as a combo box includes all the objects in the other table (in my case the Statistics table), I want to replace the combo box with an object of StatisticsForm so I can control the way I render the Statistics objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database scheme and models are incorrectly designed to solve the problem at hand.  You are defining a "has many" relationship in the wrong direction. One `Measurement` is supposed to have several `Statistics`, however one `Statistics` is not supposed to have many `Measurement`.

As your models are set up right now the `ForeignKey` is on the wrong side of the relationship. You should do this instead:

```
class Measure(models.Model):
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        result = super(Measure, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        Statistics.objects.create(name='length', measurement=self)
        Statistics.objects.create(name='section', measurement=self)
        Statistics.objects.create(name='surface', measurement=self)
        Statistics.objects.create(name='volume', measurement=self)
        Statistics.objects.create(name='diameter', measurement=self)
        return result
```

To provide the same comfort in accessing the `Statistics`s for one `Measurement` as in your current code you can add a couple of `@property` shortcuts:

```
class Measure(models.Model):
    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.statistics_set.get(name='length')
    @property
    def section(self):
        return self.statistics_set.get(name='section')
    @property
    def surface(self):
        return self.statistics_set.get(name='surface')
    @property
    def volume(self):
        return self.statistics_set.get(name='volume')
    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self.statistics_set.get(name='diameter')

class Statistics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    measurement = models.ForeignKey('Measurement')
    total = models.FloatField('Total', null=True, blank=True)
    avg = models.FloatField('Average', null=True, blank=True)
    min = models.FloatField('Minimum', null=True, blank=True)
    max = models.FloatField('Maximum', null=True, blank=True)
    standard_deviation = models.FloatField('Standard deviation', null=True, blank=True)
```

Once you fix the relationship between the objects the problem becomes much easier to solve. Instead of being `ForeignKeyFields` in the form, the `Statistics`s become proper related objects, which are routinely handled by django.

As @solarisssmoke mentioned in the comments you are looking for formsets. Here is an example from the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view) showing how to achieve what you need:

The models in question:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

And a view using `inlineformset_factory` to create the needed formset:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory


def manage_books(request, author_id):
    author = Author.objects.get(pk=author_id)
    BookInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = BookInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # Do something. Should generally end with a redirect. For example:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(author.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        formset = BookInlineFormSet(instance=author)
    return render(request, 'manage_books.html', {'formset': formset})
```

If performance becomes an issue also have a look at [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for boosting performance.